# Health check timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a simple spring boot app with a few endpoints deployed to the pcf cloud. When I am doing load testing towards them I get request time increased  on calls to my EPs and finally timeout on /health which causes my instance get restarted (as the timeout is 1sec and AFAIK there is no way to adjust it) As I understand this happens due to the fact that tomcat can't handle that many of requests given provided resources and ideally I would like to handle requests to health endpoint with high priority so that my instance doesn't fail. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Elasticity, in PCF is achieved using auto-scaling. Do you have `autoscaler` bound to your app and configured, so that PCF can scale your app instances as the load increases?

Comment: Yep, I have it configured for CPU load with bounds from 35 to 80. But it does not help as new instances don't have time to get up whereas existing ones fail with timeout on health check due to high load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is liveness check failure.

The port or http check does not respond within 1 second (invocation timeout), which indicates the app is in an unresponsive state.

The invocation timeout is configurable , below are the different options (you can set up to 180s).

- (v6) cf v3-set-health-check --invocation-timeout
- (v7) cf set-health-check --invocation-timeout
- health-check-invocation-timeout in deployment manifest when pushed
  with v3 API

Your manifest file should be like this:

---

```
applications:
- name: my-microservice   
  health-check-type: http   
  health-check-http-endpoint: /actuator/health
  timeout: 180  
  health-check-invocation-timeout: 60
```

Comment: The above changes is not reflecting in the PCF settings. I am still getting older values. Any idea?
process   health check   endpoint (for http)   invocation timeout
web       http           /actuator/health      1